# C# WPF program button click run a task until another button click stop or until cancel token valid

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am creating a WPF app where I want to have a global bool im assuming, on the first button click I’ll set this bool to true and I want it to run a task (continuously call an API method) until I click the button again and it stops it. What would be the best way to do this?

```
    private bool running = false;

    private async void BtnTrade1_Buy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!running)
        {
            running = true;
        }
        else
            running = false;

        if (running)
        {
            RunningNrunnin(running);
            //tradeClient.GetTradeHistory();
        }
    }

    public void RunningNrunnin(bool running)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            Task task = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (running)
                {
                    GetTradeHistory();
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            });
            task.Start();
        }
    }
```

Added Below

I would like to call a method over and over until the user creates a cancel request on a thread in the background. I currently had it so I can call a action (a counter) and update the GUI each second but when I try to do this same thing with a method call it executes only once.

```
// Here is the method I want to call continously until canceled
private async void HistoryTest()
        {
            cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    cancellationToken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    await Client2.GetHistory();
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                }
            }, cancellationToken.Token);

        }
public async Task GetHistory()
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await Client.Service.GetDataAsync
                    (
                        ProductType.BtcUsd,
                        5,
                        1
                    );
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything else inside the `BtnTrade1_Buy_Click` event handler, beyond toggling the `isRunning` field:

```
private bool _isRunning;

private void BtnTrade1_Buy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isRunning = !_isRunning;
}
```

The `Task` that is getting the trade history in a loop, needs to be started only once. You could start it in the `Window_Loaded` event. Storing the `Task` in a private field is a good idea, in case you decide to `await` it at some point, but if you are handling the exceptions inside the task it's not necessary.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _ = StartTradeHistoryLoopAsync(); // Fire and forget
}

private async Task StartTradeHistoryLoopAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(2000);
        if (_isRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => GetTradeHistory()); // Run in the ThreadPool
                //GetTradeHistory(); // Alternative: Run in the UI thread
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the exception
            }
        }
        await delayTask;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to stop the task when the window is closed.

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _isRunning = false;
}
```

This will stop the calls to `GetTradeHistory()`, but will not stop the loop. You may need to add one more private `bool` field to control the loop itself:

```
while (_alive) // Instead of while (true)
```

Comment: When I debug my program and did it just like your code it executes 1 time and brings the GUI back it doesnt continue to execute...

Comment: @Bigbear have you tried to run the program without the debugger attached? With Ctrl+F5.

Comment: so a quick question, would you recommend a method call like this every 1-2 secs or WebSockets for continuous data? (Trade Orders),
Also as long as I use Task.Run() is it running in the back ground? So I can continue to use the Main GUI to do other calls?

Comment: @Bigbear I haven't worked with WebSockets, so I can't give an informed advice. I guess that WebSockets are more lightweight, but it may be more complex. In any case don't quote me on that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I made a little console test app to test this so I had to change the method signatures (static) and  can't use `ButtonClick` on a console. I simulated the button click by putting as sleep between the programatic "button click".

This might get you started.

```
    private static bool isRunning = false;
    private static int clickCounter = 0;
    private static int iterationsCounter = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“Start”);
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            BtnTrade1_Buy_Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(“END”);
    }


    private static async Task BtnTrade1_Buy_Click()
    {
        iterationsCounter = 0;
        isRunning = !isRunning;
        Console.WriteLine($"Ha: {isRunning} {clickCounter++}");
        await RunningNrunnin();
    }



    private static async Task RunningNrunnin()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Runit());
    }


    private static void Runit()
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            GetTradeHistory();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }


    private static void GetTradeHistory()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello Test {iterationsCounter++}");
    }
```

Of course you wouldn't need all the counters and the `Console.WriteLine()` stuff. They are there to allow you to visualize what is happening.

Let me know if you need more info.